# App crashes while reloading the page with double param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using `react-router-dom` v5. When I hit a reload button in my app, e.g. in `/home` or `/` or `/about` the pages are loading correctly. But when I hit reload button on some double route, e.g. `/home/something` or `/something/something` the app isn't getting started! Nothing is rendered.

This happens only in development mode.

My Routes:

```
<Route path={'/about'} component={About}/>
<Route path={'/'} component={Home}/>
<Route path={'/home/:id'} component={Home}/>
<Route path={'/something/something'} component={Home}/>
<Redirect to='/' />
```

As you can see, I have a route selected for `/home:id` or `/something/something`, but still if I hit reload when being on `/home/something` or `/something/something` the app crashes.

I would expect it to redirect at least to the `/` path... but still it doesn't work neither.

**it's a big problem for me** since I cant go to nested routes and reload to fetch the data in componentDidMount...

Comment: Isn't the `home:id` route supposed to be `/home/:id`?

Comment: @innis thanks but its just a typo in my question, the error still occurs

Comment: what exactly the error that you get?

Comment: Is it logging something?

Comment: @HagaiHarari no errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `<Redirect to="/" />` change it to `<Redirect from="*" to="/" />` and add `exact` for `/` route

```js
<Route path={'/about'} component={About}/>
<Route exact path={'/'} component={Home}/>
<Route path={'/home/:id'} component={Home}/>
<Route path={'/something/something'} component={Home}/>
<Redirect from="*" to="/" />
```

Comment: Didnt change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

To get routes to redirect in this case, you need to add the `exact` prop in the routes and also wrap the routes in the `<Switch>` component. This will allow you to match the routes exactly as they appear in the address bar and match them exclusively.

Try this:

```js
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={"/about"} component={About} />
    <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
    <Route exact path={"/home/:id"} component={Home} />
    <Route exact path={"/something/something"} component={Home} />
    <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ardinghelli-6teej

References:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Comment: Didnt change anything :/

Comment: Then it might have to do with the component that's being rendered. Can you share the code for the components being rendered?